# Adding a test certificate for SSL on heroku is failing

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate

I followed the steps outlined here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-certificate-self to add a test certificate for SSL endpoint at heroku

When i try to add it by running 'heroku certs:add server.crt server.key'

I get the following error:

!    Invalid certificate or key. Please verify that your files contain a valid chain of trust, or contact support@heroku.com

Anybody have an idea what I'm missing and how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with indeed, but you can try using ssldoctor: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-ssl-doctor

Comment: Hi, what does SSL doctor do? I can see it comes into effect when adding certs. however, it's still not working for me, I tried the --bypass option too, still same error. Btw I don't have any .pem file, is that required? I didn't read any step like that on the heroku docs Thanks

Comment: It should solve make it easier to import the certificate. But it seems that the certificate is wrong. Try by using tinyca to generate certificates, usually that takes away most of the erros when generating certificates. But have you tried sending a mail to support? Also have you checked that your certificate is valid yet? Sometimes its valid from time is in the future.